# How do I install pyperclip on python? I have version 3.11.4 and I'm using Windows 11

Tags: python, pyperclip

so I am making my way through the "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" course on Udemy. I'm on lesson 8 right now. In lesson 8, the instructor just very quickly downloads pyperclip without explaining what or how he is doing it. How do I install this? I have python version 3.11.4 and I'm on windows 11. I apologize if this is ridiculous, but I'm basically still in my first few weeks of doing this stuff.

After some googling and youtubing I tried to right click the start button and click terminal window. I'm not sure exactly what to type though when it brings up the administrator window powershell to install pyperclip. I tried, "pip install pyperclip" but that didn't work and it gave an error. Another video says to go to the folder labeled, "scripts" on your homepage, but I don't have any such folder.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [the installation guide for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#ensurepip) and follow the steps to install pip.

Then run pip `pip install pyperclip` in command prompt or powershell.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers (they're not valid answers)